# In QT, can I restart an application in a way that clears the cache?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QT QGUIApplication. The first page of the stack contains a TextInput which is initially blank and requires the user to enter text and click "submit" which prompts a widgets visibility to switch to TRUE.

On the final page of the stack I want to return to the front of the stack after pressing the button "finish". I'm currently using stack.pop(null), which brings me to my first page BUT the old text is there and the widget visibility has not reset to FALSE.

How can I reset the cache when selecting "finish" to restart the application?

Comment: You have to provide [mcve] first instead of explaining your code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @folibis's comment that your question should include your code, but I think I understand enough what you are asking. It sounds like you are using a `StackView` to display different pages of your app. Next time, please try to be more clear in your question so we don't have to guess. Using `stack.pop(null)` should take you back to the first page exactly as you had left it before. If you want to wipe out your previous work and start over (clear the "cache", as you say), there are two obvious solutions:

1. Create a function to empty all the fields on your page, and then call that function after you pop.

```
function clearFields() {
    textField.text = ""
    ...
}
...
stack.pop(null)
stack.currentItem.clearFields()
```

2. Clear the stack completely instead of popping, and then re-add your first page.

```
stack.clear()
stack.push(yourFirstPage)
```